# How do I access the Binding of Isaac: Rebirth soundtrack?

Tags: steam, the-binding-of-isaac-rebirth

I have the soundtrack for The Binding of Isaac: Rebirth installed through Steam:

[image: The Binding of Isaac: Rebirth - Soundtrack - Status Installed]

**Where can I find it** in order to listen to when I'm not playing? I found a packed music.a file, but that's intentionally encrypted according to the readme in the same folder, and so it is unusable in a music player, including Steam's own music player.

Steam claims the soundtrack was released on the 4th of November, as was the game itself:

[image: Release Date: 4 Nov 2014]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The soundtrack has now appeared in `SteamApps\common\The Binding of Isaac Rebirth\The Binding of Isaac Rebirth OST`.

Answer (score 3):

From the [Known Issues](http://steamcommunity.com/app/250900/discussions/0/613941122558099449/) thread posted by the developers:

> #### The Soundtrack DLC is not working
>
> People who bought the Soundtrack DLC cannot access the music files right now.
>   Expect this to be fixed soon, sorry about the inconvenience.

Answer (score 2):

After a little more searching, the Binging of Isaac Rebirth Soundtrack can also be found on [Ridiculon's Band Camp page](http://ridiculon.bandcamp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

I guess it would be under the [Steam Music Player](http://store.steampowered.com/news/14358/).
That's where the FTL soundtrack was for me.